# Closure of range and nullspace of a normal operator under positive powers of the operator

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, invariant-subspace

Let V be a finite-dimensional inner product space. Prove that the nullspace and range of a normal operator $f$ on V are unchanged by taking any positive power $f^m$ of the operator.

I've tried proving this using invariant subspaces but have had no look so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is normal, then there is a unitary (orthogonal) $Q$ such that $AQ = Q \Lambda$, where $\Lambda$ is diagonal.

Then ${\cal R} A = {\cal R} (AQ) = Q {\cal R} \Lambda = Q {\cal R} \Lambda^m = {\cal R} (A^mQ) = {\cal R} A^m$.

Similarly, 
$\ker A = \ker (QA) = \ker (\Lambda Q^*) = \ker (\Lambda^m Q^*) = \ker (Q A^m) = \ker A^m$.